# Can we change the content of notification after a certain time or event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I am trying to change the content of notification after certain time or after I get another notification so as to show club data in notification tray.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change an already-posted notification, but you can clear existing notifications and post new ones.

Comment: Setting the alert badge to zero removes all notifications.  Posting is done through whatever mechanism you already have in place.